# How to debug missing shared library (libffmpeg.so) while running Electron App (LBRY-Desktop) on FreeBSD Linuxulator?

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, freebsd

I'm working on running an Electron Linux App on FreeBSD, namly
[lbry-desktop](https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-desktop/).

I did this

1. download https://github.com/mrclksr/linux-browser-installer
2. run from FreeBSD

   ```sh
   sudo ./linux-browser-installer chroot create
   sudo chroot /compat/ubuntu/ /bin/bash
   ```
3. run from chroot/ubuntu

   ```sh
   apt install --yes wget
   cd /root
   wget https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-desktop/releases/download/v0.51.2/LBRY_0.51.2.deb
   apt install --yes ./LBRY_0.51.2.deb
   rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libfprint-2-2\:amd64.postinst
   apt install --yes ./LBRY_0.51.2.deb
   ```
4. back to FreeBSD

   ```sh
   > /compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/lbry
   ```

I'm getting this

```sh
/compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/lbry: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fish: Job 1, '/compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/lbry' terminated by signal SIGTRAP (Trace or breakpoint trap)
```

I did some debugging, but can't get it thru.

My conclusion is, it should work, since

1. `ffmpeg.so` is present

   ```sh
   > ll /compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/
   total 195691
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1.0K Aug 20 16:22 LICENSE.electron.txt
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   4.5M Aug 20 16:22 LICENSES.chromium.html
   -rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   6.0M Aug 20 16:22 chrome-sandbox
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   176K Aug 20 16:22 chrome_100_percent.pak
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   314K Aug 20 16:22 chrome_200_percent.pak
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    10M Aug 20 16:22 icudtl.dat
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   122M Aug 20 16:22 lbry
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   238K Aug 20 16:22 libEGL.so
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   8.5M Aug 20 16:22 libGLESv2.so
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   3.0M Aug 20 16:22 libffmpeg.so
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   4.3M Aug 20 16:22 libvk_swiftshader.so
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   8.1M Aug 20 16:22 libvulkan.so
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    55B Sep  6 13:04 locales
   drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel     5B Sep  6 13:04 resources
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   4.6M Aug 20 16:22 resources.pak
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    49K Aug 20 16:22 snapshot_blob.bin
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel     4B Sep  6 13:04 swiftshader
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   167K Aug 20 16:22 v8_context_snapshot.bin
   -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   107B Aug 20 16:22 vk_swiftshader_icd.json
   > strings /compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/lbry|rg libffmpeg\.so
   libffmpeg.so
   ```

Also, from chroot

```sh
root@alef14:~# ldd /opt/LBRY/lbry |grep ffmpeg
        libffmpeg.so => /opt/LBRY/libffmpeg.so (0x0000000808e00000)
```

So I'm missing something, but can't find it.

How can I debug/solve it?

Running the program from `/compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/` dir, doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to make the program work, so I'm sharing it hoping it might help someone.

It's based on the [this article](https://vermaden.wordpress.com/2021/09/06/freebsd-desktop-part-27-configuration-netflix-signal-telegram/) and the complete commands are

```
pkg install git  # or git-lite if you prefer
git clone git@github.com:mrclksr/linux-browser-installer.git
cd linux-browser-installer

doas ./linux-browser-installer chroot create
doas chroot /compat/ubuntu bash
apt install --yes wget
cd /root
wget https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-desktop/releases/download/v0.51.2/LBRY_0.51.2.deb
apt install --yes ./LBRY_0.51.2.deb

apt remove --yes libpam-fprintd:amd64 libfprint-2-2:amd64
apt --yes autoremove

apt install --yes ./LBRY_0.51.2.deb
```

Now, it can be run from the host

```
/compat/ubuntu/opt/LBRY/lbry --no-sandbox
```